# Show/hide input text after click with multiple selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have selectbox like this

rows 1

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select id="showhide">
      <option value="0">-SELECT-</option>
      <option value="1">Show</option>
      <option value="2">Hide</option>
  </select>
  <input id="txtname" type="text" name="txtname" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

rows 2

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select id="showhide">
      <option value="0">-SELECT-</option>
      <option value="1">Show</option>
      <option value="2">Hide</option>
  </select>
  <input id="txtname" type="text" name="txtname" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

and javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showhide").change(function(){
        var valx = $('#showhide').val();
        if(valx == '1'){
            $("#txtname").show();
        }else if(valx == '2'){
            $("#txtname").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

when i use selectbox in rows 1 show/hide the inputbox in rows 1 working, but when i use selectbox in rows 2 the show/hide not working like rows 1.

how to solved this.

thankyou

Comment: @Ramanlfc. after i change to class with the same class name, this not work to. i can't use uniqname because this rows is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this changes.

In the current scenario,use `$(this)` to get `current context selection`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.showhide").change(function() {

        var valx = $(this).val();
        if (valx == '1') {
            $(this).next().show();
        } else if (valx == '2') {
            $(this).next().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Add class `class="showhide"` to your select drop-down.
Id Should be unique.So, you can not use same id twice.

HTML :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <select class="showhide">
            <option value="0">-SELECT-</option>
            <option value="1">Show</option>
            <option value="2">Hide</option>
        </select>
        <input id="txtname" type="text" name="txtname" style="display:none;">
    </form>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <select class="showhide">
            <option value="0">-SELECT-</option>
            <option value="1">Show</option>
            <option value="2">Hide</option>
        </select>
        <input id="txtname" type="text" name="txtname" style="display:none;">
    </form>
```

Comment: not work, when i change  selectbox in rows 1 and 2 the inputbox in rows 1 working and show and hide but not to input box in rows 2

Answer (score 1):

Replace `id` attribute with `name` in `select`, and remove `id` attribute from `input`, because `id` attribute must be unique over all document.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select name="showhide">
      <option value="0">-SELECT-</option>
      <option value="1">Show</option>
      <option value="2">Hide</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="txtname" style="display:none;">
</form>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select name="showhide">
      <option value="0">-SELECT-</option>
      <option value="1">Show</option>
      <option value="2">Hide</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="txtname" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name='showhide']").change(function(){
        $(this).siblings('input[name="txtname"]').toggle(this.value == 1);
    });
});
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/pavijufige/edit?html,js,output